# problems getting links from youtube channel with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, youtube, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a youtube channel and return all of the links for each video of this channel, however when I try to print out these links, I only get a few links that have nothing to do with the videos. I am suspecting the videos may be loaded by Javascript, so would there we a way to even do this with beautifulsoup? Will I have to use selenium? Can somebody please help me and do some testing. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('scanning page...')

youtuber = 'memeulous'
result = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/' + youtuber + '/videos')
status = result.status_code
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a')

if status == 200:
    print('valid URL, grabbing uploads...')
else:
    print('invalid URL, status code: ' + str(status))
    quit()

print(links)
```

and here is my output:

```
scanning page...
valid URL, grabbing uploads...
[<a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">About</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/press/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Press</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/copyright/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Copyright</a>, <a href="/t/contact_us" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Contact us</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/creators/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Creators</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/ads/" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Advertise</a>, <a href="https://developers.google.com/youtube" slot="guide-links-primary" style="display: none;">Developers</a>, <a href="/t/terms" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Terms</a>, <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en-GB/policies/privacy/" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Privacy</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/about/policies/" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Policy and Safety</a>, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks?utm_campaign=ytgen&amp;utm_source=ythp&amp;utm_medium=LeftNav&amp;utm_content=txt&amp;u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fhowyoutubeworks%3Futm_source%3Dythp%26utm_medium%3DLeftNav%26utm_campaign%3Dytgen" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">How YouTube works</a>, <a href="/new" slot="guide-links-secondary" style="display: none;">Test new features</a>]
[Finished in 4.0s]
```

as you can see, no video links.

Comment: You don't have to use selenium, but you might want to use YouTube's API. You're not getting anything, because the site's rendered dynamically by JS.

Comment: @baduker would there be anyway at all to do this with beautifulsoup? I have no idea how to work the API and i don't know how difficult it would be.

Comment: It's not as difficult as you may think. There are plenty of wrappers in Python for YouTube's API. And no, there's no way to fetch what you want just with bs4. Here's a quickstart - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be with the following code:

```
import requests

api_key = "PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE!"
yt_user = "memeulous"
api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={yt_user}&key={api_key}"

response = requests.get(api_url).json()

playlist_id = response["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

channel_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?" \
              f"part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId={playlist_id}&key={api_key}"


def get_video_ids(vid_data: dict) -> list:
    return [_id["contentDetails"]["videoId"] for _id in vid_data["items"]]


def build_links(vid_ids: list) -> list:
    return [f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={_id}" for _id in vid_ids]


def get_all_links() -> list:
    all_links = []
    url = channel_url
    while True:
        res = requests.get(url).json()
        all_links.extend(build_links(get_video_ids(res)))
        try:
            paging_token = res["nextPageToken"]
            url = f"{channel_url}&pageToken={paging_token}"
        except KeyError:
            break
    return all_links


print(get_all_links())
```

This gets you all the video links (`469`) for the `memeulous` user.

```
['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L8_isnyGfg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogpaiD2e-ss', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oH-nJe9XMN0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUcbKl4qe5g', ...
```

You can get the total video count from the `videos_data` object likes this:

`print(f"Total videos: {videos_data['pageInfo']['totalResults']}")`

I hope this helps and will get you started. All you need to do, is get the API key for the YouTube Data API.

Comment: How would I get this to show all of the videos, rather than just 50.

Comment: Then you would use something called a paging token. I've updated the answer so it fetches all the videos.